# string cutter php script not work properly

Tags: php, string

I am using below script for cut my strings.

```
$titlex = strip_tags($title);
if (strlen($titlex) > 35) {

    // truncate string
    $stringCutx = substr($titlex, 0, 35);

    // make sure it ends in a word so assassinate doesn't become ass...
    $titlex = substr($stringCutx, 0, strrpos($stringCutx, ' ')).'...<a href="">read MOre</a>'; 
}
```

but its not work well in all conditions likes if string have 2 white spaces it not work default it some time cut those string or some time not. and if string don't have any white space it not cut string however if it Long storing but its not cut.. I am try to solve this issue but not found any solution because of experience. how i solve this issue ?

Comment: I couldn't help noticing your 13375p34k: `read MOre`. Are you sure you want to use a zero?

Comment: Good luck with multibyte characters, though

Comment: @TimS. i just as default this script dont know why some values zero and i try to change these but its not working

Comment: @Marcel hey do you have any solution ? for these issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go for wordwrap

```
$titlex = strip_tags($title);
$len=35;
if (strlen($titlex) > $len) {
    $stringCutx=explode("\n",wordwrap($titlex,$len,"\n",true),2);
    $stringCutx=$stringCutx[0].'...<a href="">read MOre</a>';
}
```

Comment: dude it nothing response i am try to reduce value of $len but not work.

Comment: oh i am usning last varialbe as $titlex now tryn to $stringCutx and itys working.

Answer (score -1):

```
$titlex = strip_tags($title);
if (strlen($titlex) > 35) {
    $stringCutx = substr($titlex, 0, 35);
    if (strlen($stringCutx) >= 35 && isset($title[$titlex])) {
        if ($title[$titlex] != ' ') {
            $pos = strpos($title, ' ', 35);
            if ($pos == 0) { 
                $res = $text;
            } else {
                $temp = substr($title, 35, $pos - 35);
                $res = $res.$temp.'...<a href="">read MOre</a>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dude you are using some where varialbe $title and $titlex is 2 variable also same name? or not